# Find relative position of axes of cube after rotation

Tags: rotation, three.js, quaternions

I am rotating a cube through a series of 90 degree rotations using quaternions and I want to be able to get relative positions of the quaternions after a rotation compared with its original position that I have stored.

IE I'd like to know which axis is now equivalent to the original x axis (and if it is inverted), and so on...

I'm using threejs, but I'm sure that's not necessary for answering.

Comment: Do you mean this? `var dir = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ); dir.applyQuaternion( q1 ); dir.applyQuaternion( q2 ); ...`

Comment: Oh shit, of course it would be that easy. You mean, just make a vector for each axis and rotate it along with the quaternion, right?

Comment: So it looks like if I do this, then I can just check which portion of the vector equals 1 or -1, to determine which axis is is equivalent to. Thank you very much. If you make this an aswer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It is probably best not to test for equality, due to roundoff. Test for greater than 0.9 or less than -0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern to determine the direction the x-axis is pointing after applying a series of rotations.

```
var dir = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
dir.applyQuaternion( q1 );
dir.applyQuaternion( q2 ); // etc...
```

To see it visually, you can add axes as a child of your cube mesh. The axes will be rotated automatically.

```
var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 );
mesh.add( axes );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thank you, I just finished trying it out, and it seems to work fine if there's a single rotation, but when there are compound rotations along different axes, they get messed up. I made a quick fiddle to show what I'm working with, use the arrow keys to rotate the box. And you'll see an alert of the results, and you can compare that to the visual.

https://jsfiddle.net/dzvjf36a/

Comment: I am accepting this, but for some reason I had to invert the quaternion for it to work, I assume it's a quirk of my implementation.